# withContext not getting executed

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

startActivity(..) is not getting called from within the withContext block and also delay is not getting called.

startActivity(..) gets called if I move it out of the withContext block.

```
        var image: Bitmap? = null
        lifecycleCoroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val conn = URL(content.image).openConnection()
            conn.connect()
            val inputStream = conn.getInputStream()
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
            inputStream.close()

            val file = image?.let {
                saveFile(it, "file")
            }

            file?.let {
                intent.putExtra(
                    Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        context,
                        environmentProvider.fileProviderAuthority,
                        it
                    )
                )
            }
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                startActivity(context, intent, null)
            }
            delay(1000)
        }
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the code before the `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` doesn't error/throw an exception, since you are opening an IO thread earlier these just get ignored but the code behind them doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a lifecycle scope, so your coroutine is cancelled if the launching Activity goes out of scope. However, a cancelled coroutine will keep running until the next point where it supports cancellation. Calling a suspend function from the standard coroutine library, such as `withContext()` is one way to support cancellation.

So for example, if your coroutine was up around the `inputStream.close()` line when the user rotates the screen, then the lifecycle is ended and the coroutine is cancelled, but it will keep executing all the code under that until it reaches the next suspend function, which is `withContext()`. Then it finally can halt execution and your `startActivity` function will never be reached.

This is why the `startActivity` function still gets called if you pull it out of the `withContext` block. This is not a good thing! Your coroutine should support prompt cancellation to avoid memory leaks. It is also not safe to call `startActivity` off the main thread. You might have a runtime exception as a result.

Looking at your code overall, this code should probably be moved into a ViewModel so if the screen rotates while the image is being loaded, that progress won't be lost.

Comment: I tried to execute the above code and I didn't rotate the activity. startActivity is still not getting called. 

Also to your point "Your coroutine should support prompt cancellation to avoid memory leaks" Can you explain how can this be achieved?

Comment: Try wrapping all your coroutine's code in `try { ... } catch(e: CancellationException) { Log.e(TAG, e); throw e }` To find out what's cancelling your coroutine. It might be some other cause than a screen rotation. [This article](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html) explains how to make a coroutine cooperate with cancellation.